# php preg_match why on earth doesnt it work?

Tags: php

this is just so bang head on wall situation. this pattern works perfectly in javascript. and i have no idea what to do.

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_Yu-Gi-Oh!_BAM_cards'); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$chHtml = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$patt = '/<table class="wikitable sortable card-list">[\s\S]*?<\/table/im'; //////////////this 
preg_match($patt, $chHtml, $matches);
```

is the problem line

if i make it greedy

```
[\s\S]*
```

it works fine but it goes till the last

Comment: Parsing HTML with regexes? [That's not advisable...](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/344643)

Comment: Don't use regular expressions for HTML, use an XML/HTML parser! See http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/838733

Comment: Or if you want something helpful, see this post instead: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php

Comment: Thanks all! But its just bugging me now why on earth doesnt it work lol. I even tried using the u flag. Its just so unexplainable

Comment: I worked for like an hour, then read the php articles on the php official site on PCRE then I tried some more then took a nap woke up and tried more and failed. Then posted here.

Comment: Can you try this regex: `$patt = '~<table class="wikitable sortable card-list">.*?</table~is';`

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with the pattern, the problem is that you need a larger backtrack limit than the default.

**Explaining:**

In regex problems like that always check for errors using the `preg_last error()`.

If you use it in the specific response from the site you submitted, since this is a resource problem and smaller texts do not raise the error, you will see that you are getting a `PREG_BACKTRACK_LIMIT_ERROR`.

**Solution:**

To overcome this limit you can raise it with the following in the start of your script:

```
ini_set ('pcre.backtrack_limit', 10000000);
```